# How to disable the error C4700 locally when compiled with /we4700

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider the following code

```
int TestReadUninitStack()
{
    printf("Reading an uninitialized stack variable\n");
    int i;
    volatile int j = i;
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Uninitialized stack variable read not detected!\n");
    return 2;
}
```

When I compiled my project with [/we4700](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx), this piece of code fails with Compile Error

```
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used
```

To get around the compile Error, I added a pragma to temporarily disabled [C4700](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx) Warning around the code block, but unfortunately that does not seem to work

```
int TestReadUninitStack()
{
    printf("Reading an uninitialized stack variable\n");
    #pragma warning( push )
    #pragma warning( disable : 4700 )
    int i;
    volatile int j = i;
    #pragma warning( pop ) 
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Uninitialized stack variable read not detected!\n");
    return 2;
}
```

Any idea, how to possibly deal with it?

Comment: Have you tried `memcpy(&j, &i, sizeof i)`?

Comment: @moshbear: And why should I do that?

Comment: It bypasses assignment with the  '=' operator. This can let you copy the value without triggering C4700. I.e., it's an alternative form of assignment that might outsmart the compiler just enough to not have it emit diagnostic C4700. I haven't tested it, so it might not work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: The memcpy method silences the "uninitialized local variable used" warning in gcc 4.7.3, but produces the warning of cv-qualification being discarded, i.e. cv-qualified T* in place of T * restrict. Your mileage may vary, and you can just implement a wrapper function that satisfies the cv-rules.

Comment: Also, why do you need "volatile"? Does the code break or generate incorrect ASM without it?